# How to apply the Geiger–Nuttall rule to find half-life?

Tags: kinetics, energy, nuclear-chemistry

I'm having trouble understanding the Geiger–Nuttall rule for α-particle decay. From the textbook I'm using, the rule is defined as

$$
\log(t_{1/2}) = A + \frac{B}{\sqrt{Q_\alpha}},
$$

where the constants $A$ and $B$ have a $Z$ dependence. Here's a Geiger–Nuttall plot of the logarithm of the half-life (s) versus the square root of the $Q_α$ value (MeV):

[image: Geiger– Nuttall plot]

How do we use the above equation to find the half-life? More specifically, can we use that to find the half-life of $\ce{^{226}Ra}$ nuclei?

Comment: I doubt it is used to obtain half life, unless it is extremely short or long. If you look at the logarithmic scale, is is very sensitive to values of A,B and Q.

Comment: Find alpha particle energy from radium-226 decay and apply on the the formula, getting values A and B from the line for Z=88 ( better if they are tabulated somewhere).